# How to revoke GitHub's access to Heroku?

Tags: github, heroku, deployment

[image]

I have added another github account to heroku dashboard and i want to remove this account from heroku and connect another github account. As you can see there is no disconnect button as such. How can i remove this github account from heroku app?

Answer (score 1):

Got it. Go to account settings and to application tab, from there you can revoke access to third party services such as github.